# How do I trigger a function when using HtmlElementView Widget?

Tags: javascript, html, flutter, dart, iframe

I am trying to call a function (`widget.onTap()`) in the following code

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    widget.onTap()
  },
  child: Container(
     height: 1.9 * widget.height,
     width: 1.2 * widget.width,
        child: HtmlElementView(viewType: 'liquid-button', key: UniqueKey(),),
     ),
  )
```

I have registered my **"liquid-button"** as such

```
ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory('liquid-button', (int viewId) {
var element = html.IFrameElement()
        ..style.border = 'none'
        ..srcdoc = """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
          <head>
          </head>
          <body>
            <svg class="liquid-button"
          ...
         """
   return element;
});
```

The problem is I cannot capture anything from the user no matter what I try. The GestureDetector doesn't work, neither do the buttons. I am able to trigger some code in JS, but I need to handle it in Dart. Is this possible ?

Comment: What if you replace `GestureDetector` with `InkWell` ?

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: put a print inside onTap and see if that being called

Comment: it's obviously I did try that prior to asking this question

Comment: @Damian do you have any solution?

Comment: I have stopped trying. I did found a solution though, but I doubt you will like it anyway. I made a backend and then used websockts to connect to it and js would forward messages to backend through websocket then back to dart and it did work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the workaround for this one.
So basically, we can take advantage of window.localStorage where it can be accessed from both flutter and html, and add listener in flutter for any change in window.localStorage

1. Add listener inside the flutter

   final Storage webLocalStorage = window.localStorage;

   htmlListener(){
   String buttonClicked = webLocalStorage["buttonClicked"];
   if(buttonClicked=="yes"){
   //do whatever
   }else{
   Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100), (){
   htmlListener();
   });
   }
   }
2. Do some change to the webstorage in the HTML

   var webLocalStorage = window.localStorage;
   webLocalStorage["buttonClicked"] = "yes";

And you can do the same vice versa, that is listen from html, change in flutter.